# plot pandas data frame graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

everyone I want to display the open price as x-axis and security name as y-axis using matplotlib as my data  is stored on  pandas dataframe graph results nothing.thank you for your help.

```
import requests.packages.urllib3
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()


dfs = pd.read_excel('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',header=0,dtype={'Open Price (Rs.)':np.float64,'Close Price (Rs.)':np.float64}, sheetname=None)
xl=pd.ExcelFile('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',header=0,dtype={'Open Price (Rs.)':np.float64})
p=xl.sheet_names




matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
print(dfs['D-0']['Open Price (Rs.)'])
plt.plot(y=dfs['D-0']['Open Price (Rs.)'], x=dfs['D-0']['Security Name'], kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

here 'D-0' is my sheetname contains stock data here is the link of my data
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_RSbeIckLLeR0ZJelQtY0tUbTQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add `thousands=','` parameter for remove `,` in `float`s:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('Movement of BSE RIK.xlsx',
                     header=0,
                     dtype={'Open Price (Rs.)':np.float64,'Close Price (Rs.)':np.float64}, 
                     sheetname=None, 
                     thousands=',')
```

and then [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
dfs['D-0'].plot.bar(y='Open Price (Rs.)', x='Security Name')
```

But there is a lot data:

[image: graph]